# Optimal permutation of matrix rows and columns

Tags: sorting, permutations

Let $M$ be a square matrix and $S(M) = \sum_{i<j} m_{i,j}$ the sum of the elements in the upper triangular part of $M$. Is there an efficient algorithm to find a permutation matrix $A$ that minimizes $S(A M A^{\top})$